# asp net inline label text vs label control

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, inline-code

to paint labels on an asp .net webpage, is it better to use inline code like:

`<div><%$ Resources:TextResource, Name %></div>`

or set it as a label property like:

`<div><asp:Label ID="GuardarButton" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:TextResource, Name %>" /></div>`

I'm asking because label will use viewstate and won't have to read .resx file on every postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6 of one half dozen of the other. One requires viewstate, which requires processing/deserialization. the other involves reading a cached resource.

If you are looking to eliminate viewstate/trim it down, use the resource file otherwise viewstate (assuming many controls on the page).

Otherwise, it doesn't much matter.

Comment: great, I'll stay with caching, much easier that way, ty!

Comment: what if I do it like this? <div><%= Resources.Labels.Name %></div>, will it still use caching?

Comment: I believe the same thing applies